# Google Drive Generate List of Files and Folders

Tags: google-drive-api

Hello stackoverflow wizards I am in need of some help.  I am attempting to download all files and folders from my companies shared drive.  I also need to download the sub folders and their files, all of this must be exported to a google sheet.  Now I have the code below that works on just a folder but with the hundreds of folders and sub folders we have it would take me forever to do it by hand.  How can I modify this to achieve my goal?

```
 // replace your-folder below with the folder for which you want a listing
function listFolderContents() {
  var foldername = 'your-folder';
  var folderlisting = 'listing of folder ' + foldername;

  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername)
  var folder = folders.next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(folderlisting);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow( ['name', 'link'] );

  var file;
  var name;
  var link;
  var row;
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    link = file.getUrl();
    sheet.appendRow( [name, link] );     
  }  
};
```

Comment: I should specify that I am not downloading the files themselves just the names and their folder structure.  I am basically trying to have an excel document filled with all the names and their locations.

Comment: The question has been answered here already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274928/how-to-list-all-files-in-google-drive-in-a-folder-with-a-set-name